git p4 clone says "No changes to import!" from virtual stream
I'm trying to use git-p4 for the first time ever, and I can't get it to clone my depot. Instead, I am seeing this:
enno@pop-os:~/work$ git p4 clone //Initech/tpsreports@all
Importing from //Initech/tpsreports@all into tpsreports
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/enno/work/tpsreports/.git/
No changes to import!
Not checking out any branch, use "git checkout -q -b master <branch>"

The resulting directory is empty except for the .git subdirectory.
What reason could there be for this command to not import anything from my depot?

What happens if you run p4 changes //Initech/tpsreports/...?

Doesn't print anything. I'm starting to suspect this has something to do with tpsreports being a virtual stream, because I get more success using the main stream.

I think git p4 clone takes a depot path, not a stream name.

Maybe it didn't import any changes because you already did this before ("Reinizialized existing Git repository") and there isn't anything new?

git p4 clone requires a depot path (minus the trailing ... wildcard, confusingly), not a stream name.
For most stream types, the stream name corresponds roughly to a depot path that is exactly the same as the stream name, but virtual streams are views of their parent stream, and actually refer to a subset of its depot path(s); the depot path corresponding to the virtual stream's name is usually going to be completely empty.  (When you're using streams within Perforce, you usually don't have to be aware of this, because your client is associated with the stream you're working in, and the client is automatically generated to give you the correct view of the depot.)
Do:
p4 switch //Initech/tpsreports
p4 where //...

and you'll see which depot path //Initech/tpsreports corresponds to.  (It's probably something like //Initech/main/tpsreports/....)
That depot path is the path you'll want to provide as an argument to git p4 clone.

And it would be a good addition to mention that, you can then run git p4 clone --use-client-spec with the depot path. This will automatically use the stream if you had set it in the client spec.

In my experience, I always run with -v, and I found --use-client-spec will call p4 where before downloading files. It's quite slow because I have a heavy exclusion list, but so far it works.
